# Remove exposed filters in Views

Tags: 8, views

I have a `ViewExecutable` object and would like to remove the filters depending on certain arguments. I'm passing in different arguments to the View using setArguments but can't seem to find a way to either see the current filters or remove them.

There a $filter property on the object but Xdebug comes back with null on that. Is this something I can do with the ViewExecutable object or will there be some theming involved?

Thanks!